# How to unit test an endpoint that accepts list of id's in a path variable?

Tags: java, rest, junit, junit4

**Problem**

I have an endpoint that accepts a list of ids in a path variable and I am unable to pass input in the unit test.

I know the input will be of the form

> Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Below is my code**

```
@GetMapping("/{noteIds}")
public String getNotes(
        @PathVariable List<String> noteIds) {
    String methodName = "getNotes";
return "hello";
}
```

**Junit for the same**

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/{noteIds}", Arrays.asList("123","145"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
```

**Expected Input**

localhost:port/1,2,3,4 (I am passing like this in the unit test)

**Expected Output**

Success

**Actual Output**

Bad Format Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing wrong input to the endpoint. instead of passing `/{noteIds}` you should pass `/123,145`

for example:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/123,145")
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
```